# MassTransit Activity Fault with parameters

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, message-queue, masstransit

I am currently using Masstransit in with the [Courier](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/advanced/courier) pattern.

I´ve set up an Activity which may fail, and I want to be able to subscribe to this failure and act accordingly.

My problem is, even though I can subscribe to the failure, and even see the exception that caused the failure, I am unable to pass any arguments to it.

For testing purposes, supose I have the following activity:

```
public class MyActivity : ExecuteActivity<MyMessage>
{
    public Task<ExecutionResult> Execute(ExecuteContext<MyMessage> context)
    {
        try
        {
           // .... some code
            throw new FaultException<RegistrationRefusedData>(
                new RegistrationRefusedData(RegistrationRefusedReason.ItemUnavailable));
            // .... some code
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(context.Faulted(ex));
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is in the reason (`RegistrationRefusedReason`) I am passing as a argument of the exception. If I subscribe a `RoutingSlipActivityFaulted` consumer, I can *almost* get all the information I need:

```
public class ActivityFaultedConsumer : IMessageConsumer<RoutingSlipActivityFaulted>
{
    public void Consume(RoutingSlipActivityFaulted message)
    {
        string exceptionMessage = message.ExceptionInfo.Message; // OK
        string messageType = message.ExceptionInfo.ExceptionType; // OK
        RegistrationRefusedReason reason =  ??????;
    }
}
```

I feel like I am missing something important here, (maybe misusing the pattern?).

Is there any other way to get parameters from a faulted activity ?

Comment: I guess if I had a `context.FaultedWithVariables` at the activity that would work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the case you're describing isn't a `Fault`. It's a failure to meet a business condition. In this case, you wouldn't want to retry the transaction, you'd want to terminate it. To notify the initiator of the routing slip, you'd `Publish` a business event signifying that the transaction was not completed due to the business condition.

For instance, in your case, you may do something like:

```
context.Publish<RegistrationRefused>(new {
    CustomerId = xxx,
    ItemId = xxxx,
    Reason = "Item was unavailable"
    });

context.Terminate();
```

This would terminate the routing slip (the subsequent activities would not be executed), and produce a `RoutingSlipTerminated` event.

That's the proper way to end a routing slip due to a business condition or rule. Exceptions are for exceptional behavior only, since you'll likely want to retry them to handle the failure.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. But, will the `Terminate` method start compensating previous activities ? I need the whole routing slip to have a consistent transaction...

Comment: Just tested... it doesn´t . Should I send the message, & use Faulted()  in this case, or am i misusing it ? (great job on mt btw)

Comment: Yes, if you want to compensate, throw an exception and still publish your event to have the business context.

Answer (score 1):

Kinda raising this from the dead, but I really haven't found a neat solution to this.

**Here is my scenario:**

1. I want to implement a request/response, but I want to wait for the execution of a routing slip.
2. As Fabio, I want to compensate for any previous activities and I want to pass data back to the request client in case of a fault.

Conveniently, Chris provided a `RoutingSlipRequestProxy`/`RoutingSlipResponseProxy` which does just that. I've found 2 approaches, but both of them seem very hacky to me.

**Approach 1:**

1. The request client waits for `ISimpleResponse` or `ISimpleFailResponse`.
2. `RoutingSlipRequestProxy` sets the `ResponseAddress` in the variables.
3. The activity sends `ISimpleFailResponse` to the `ResponseAddress`.
4. The client waits for either response
5. The `RoutingSlipResponseProxy` sends back `Fault<ISimpleResponse>` to the `ResponseAddress`.

From what I see the hackiness comes from step 4/5 and their order. I am pretty sure it works, but it could easily stop working in case messages are consumed out-of-order.

*Sample code*: https://github.com/steliyan/Sample-RequestResponse/commit/3fcb196804d9db48617a49c7a8f8c276b47b03ef

**Approach 2:**

1. The request client waits for `ISimpleResponse` or `ISimpleFailResponse`.
2. The activity calls `ReviseItirery` with the variables and adds a faulty activity.*
3. The faulty activity faults
4. The `RoutingSlipResponseProxy2` get the `ValidationErrors` and sends back `ISimpleFailResponse` to the `ResponseAddress`.

* The activity needs to be `Activity` and not `ExecuteActivity` because there is no overload of `ReviseItinerary` with variables but with no activity log.

This approach seems hacky because an additional fault activity is added to the itinerary, just to be able to add a variable to the routing slip.

*Sample code*: https://github.com/steliyan/Sample-RequestResponse/commit/e9644fa683255f2bda8ae33d8add742f6ffe3817

**Conclusion:**
Looking at MassTransit code, it doesn't seem like a problem to add a `FaultedWithVariables` overload. However, I think Chris' point is that there should be a better way to design the workflow, but I am not sure about that.